# Getting "Error HRESULT E FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component," while creating ASP.NET Web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

[image: Screen1 : creating new asp.net web application]
[image: Screen1 : selecting empty aaplication template]
[image: Got this error after creating]

My Visual Studio version is community 2022.

I was expecting that my application should be created.

I tried following solutions :

- deleted all things and reinstall the application but didn't work
- Tried repair option present under Visual Studio installer

Comment: I enabled the backup for my OneDrive because it was previously turned off. This was causing me to have difficulty accessing my IIS Express folder and the files located within my Documents folder. By syncing the specific folder with OneDrive, I was able to regain access and successfully resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I enabled the backup for my OneDrive because it was previously turned off. This was causing me to have difficulty accessing my IIS Express folder and the files located within my Documents folder. By syncing the specific folder with OneDrive, I was able to regain access and successfully resolve the issue.

Comment: Your answer is helpful, you can mark it so that it can help more people